# I am working on an html 5 canvas and trying to draw circles on it, but as I trying to use a loop all disappears

Tags: javascript, for-loop, canvas, geometry

All good until I trying to put the for loop in(no matter what I am meant to use the loop for).

```
 <canvas id="MyCanvas" width="400" height="400"
style="border:1px solid #000000;">
</canvas>

<script>
  function(){
  var c = document.getElementById("MyCanvas");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(200,200,200,0,2*Math.PI);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(200,0,10,0,2*Math.PI);
  ctx.stroke();
  for(int i=0; i<2; i++){

      return i;}
  }

</script>
```

Comment: What is the point of that loop? You never even call the function, which you never named. It will always return 0.

Comment: I want to do something with that for loop, but as I put it down, everything disappears, what I drawn before... no matter what is in the loop.

Comment: 1. change `int` to `var`. 2. Give name to your function. and then call wherever you want :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your code refactored:

- **Save each circle definition in a javascript object:**

  ```
  var circle1={x:200,y:200,radius:200};
  var circle2={x:200,y:0,radius:10};
  ```
- **Save all the circle-objects in an array:**

  ```
  var circles=[];
  circles.push(circle1);
  circles.push(circle2);
  ```
- **Create a function that draws 1 circle from a specified circle-object:**

  ```
    function drawCircle(circle){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(circle.x,circle.y,circle.radius,0,2*Math.PI);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.stroke();
    }
  ```
- **Create a function that iterates through the array and draws all the circles:**

  ```
    function drawAll(){
        for(var i=0;i<circles.length;i++){     
            drawCircle(circles[i]);
        }  
    }
  ```

**Putting it all together...Here's a demo:**

```js
var c=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;


var circles=[];
circles.push({x:200,y:200,radius:200});
circles.push({x:200,y:0,radius:10});
drawAll();

function drawAll(){
  for(var i=0;i<circles.length;i++){     
    drawCircle(circles[i]);
  }
}

function drawCircle(circle){
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(circle.x,circle.y,circle.radius,0,2*Math.PI);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.stroke();
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=400 height=400></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no `int` keyword in JavaScript. You should use the `var` keyword instead. Also note that each function can only have 1 returned value. The `for` loop in your code doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: tried to change it but makes no difference, pls be aware of that the for loop is meant to do something else, but I couldnt work it out because (as I described) all disappeared, that I done before.

Comment: @user3084465 If using `var` instead of the `int` doesn't solve the issue, it doesn't mean that `int` is not a problem, it means there are more that 1 problem in your code. How do you call the function? Why it doesn't have _name_?

Answer (score 0):

In html

```
<canvas id="MyCanvas" width="400" height="400"
style="border:1px solid #000000;">
</canvas>
```

In script

```
</script>
  for(var i=0; i<2; i++){ 
  var c = document.getElementById("MyCanvas");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(200,200,50,0,2*Math.PI);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(200,10,10,0,2*Math.PI);
  ctx.stroke();
}

</script>
```

see jsfiddle [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ct2jfocq/)