# Push random array object on canvas

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, cordova, canvas

I try to make a animation with circles. Every second should become a circle become pushed on the canvas. One of the three circles should picked random, because the color of the ball should be random. How can I push them every second random picked on the canvas?

This is some code([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26350870/i-am-working-on-an-html-5-canvas-and-tying-to-draw-circles-on-it-but-as-i-tryin)) I found on stackoverflow and I edit it a bit for me:

```
var circle1={color: blue};
var circle2={color: yellow};
var circle3={color: orange};

var circles=[];
circles.push(circle1);
circles.push(circle2);
circles.push(circle3);

function drawCircle(circle){
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(ballx * 108, canvasHeight / 2, x*5, 0, 2*Math.PI, false);
      ctx.fillStyle = 'circle.color';
      ctx.fill();

  }
```

this is my  actually code:

```
 window.onload = window.onresize = function() {
  var C = 1; // canvas width to viewport width ratio
  var el = document.getElementById("myCanvas");


  var viewportWidth = window.innerWidth;
  var viewportHeight = window.innerHeight;

  var canvasWidth = viewportWidth * C;
  var canvasHeight = viewportHeight;
  el.style.position = "fixed";
  el.setAttribute("width", canvasWidth);
  el.setAttribute("height", canvasHeight);
  var x = canvasWidth / 100;
  var y = canvasHeight / 100;
var ballx = canvasWidth / 100;
var n;


  window.ctx = el.getContext("2d");
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
  // draw triangles


  function init() {
        ballx;      
        return setInterval(main_loop, 1000);
  }




  function draw() {   
        var counterClockwise = false;

   ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);

    //first halfarc
   ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x * 80, y * 80, y * 10, 0 * Math.PI, 1 * Math.PI, counterClockwise);
    ctx.lineWidth = y * 1;
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
    ctx.stroke();



    //third halfarc
   ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x * 20, y * 80, y * 10, 0 * Math.PI, 1 * Math.PI, counterClockwise);
    ctx.lineWidth = y * 1;
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
    ctx.stroke();



    // draw stop button
    ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(x * 87, y * 2);
      ctx.lineTo(x * 87, y * 10);
      ctx.lineWidth = x;
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(x * 95, y * 2);
      ctx.lineTo(x * 95, y * 10);
      ctx.lineWidth = x;
      ctx.stroke();
//circle

var radius = x * 5;
    ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(ballx * 108, canvasHeight / 2, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
      ctx.fillStyle = 'yellow';
      ctx.fill(); 

  }

  function update() {
    ballx -= 0.1;


    if (ballx < 0) {
      ballx = -radius;         


    }

  }







  function main_loop() {
    draw();
    update();
    collisiondetection();

  }


  init();

            function initi() {
                console.log('init');
                // Get a reference to our touch-sensitive element
                var touchzone = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
                // Add an event handler for the touchstart event
                touchzone.addEventListener("mousedown", touchHandler, false);
            }

            function touchHandler(event) {
                // Get a reference to our coordinates div
                var can = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
                // Write the coordinates of the touch to the div
                if (event.pageX < x * 50 && event.pageY > y * 10) {
                    ballx += 1;
                } else if (event.pageX > x * 50 && event.pageY > y * 10 ) {
                    ballx -= 1;
                }

                console.log(event, x, ballx);

                draw();


            }
            initi();
            draw();
}
```

Comment: I tested your code. Your code is drawing a circle and move it in horizontal direction. So my only question is you want to select a circle from three different circles and after that the selected circle will move horizontally (using update function) or you want to select new circle (at the time of update function call).

Comment: the yellow moving circle is only here to show you a demo how the random picked circle should be act, also "want to select new circle (at the time of update function call)" I think and at the beginning in my draw function should be too select a random circle :)